# Measure of the Cantor set plus the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sumset

The Sum of 2 sets of Measure zero might well be very large for example, the sum of $x$-axis and $y$-axis, is nothing but the whole plane. Similarly one can ask this question about Cantor sets:

If $C$ is the cantor set, then what is the measure of $C+C$?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are asking the case where $C$ is the Cantor ternary set, then you can show that $C+ C$ is actually $[0,2]$.

For more general Cantor sets, you can find a description in the paper: On the topological structure of the arithmetic sum of two Cantor sets, P Mendes and F Oliveira, available at http://iopscience.iop.org/0951-7715/7/2/002 .

Comment: George S: Excellent article man! Thanks +1

Comment: @Chandru: No problem. You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 31):

Here is the full question from Halmos's *Problems for mathematicians, young and old*:
[image]

Here's the hint:

[image]

And here's the solution:

[image]

Comment: Were you ever a detective in a previous life? No $h*t. :)

Comment: @George S.: In this case, I just happen to be a Halmos fan who is also a fan of citing sources.