# Is the sum of Lebesgue-zero sets still a Lebesgue-zero set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> ***Question:*** Given $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with lebesgue-measure zero, is the set
> $$ A + B := \{ a + b \mid a \in A,\,b \in B\}$$
> also of lebesgue-measure zero?

I have not yet taken any measure theory courses; up until now I know the Lebesgue integral and what a measure zero set is. I cannot think of an example (or counter-example) myself, and am keen to see what you think.

Comment: Yes for a countable sum! But not if you take an uncountable sum, and you should see some easy counter examples there :)

Comment: Not necessarily: if $C$ is the [middle-thirds Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), $C+C=[0,2]$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945351/if-c-is-the-cantor-set-then-cc-0-2), the links in Martin Sleziak’s comment under that question, and the link in my answer to that question.

Comment: @OsamaGhani See Brian's comment! (Possible point of of confusion here: "sum" is *not* "union" in this context.)

Comment: Oops, definitely misunderstood!