# Find Lebesgue Null Set A so that A-A is a Neighbourhood of zero

Tags: lebesgue-measure

I try to solve the following question:

Show that there is a Lebesgue null set A so that A-A is a neighbourhood of zero; where $A-A :=\{x-y|x,y\in A\}$.

I really don't no how to do this.

Thanks to everyone who can help.

Comment: Please edit the question, what is A-A ?

Comment: @seamp $A-A=\{a-a'\,|\,a,a'\in A\}$.

Comment: Not knowing how to do something doesn't mean you can't try. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions

Comment: @CalvinKhor The OP is a new contributor. Besides, someone not familiar with the Cantor set any not get any idea at all on this question. Let us be sympathetic to new contributors.

Comment: The title asks for a result that is false, so the title should be reworded a bit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, I was terse but did not mean to not have sympathy. A course ideally provides students with enough tools to have a fighting chance, and that is what I was hoping for the OP to provide us

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You are right about the title. OP should change the title.

Comment: Sorry, have changed the titel.

Answer (score 0):

If $C$ is the Cantor set then $C-C=[-1,1]$ and $C$ has measure $0$. To prove that $C-C=[-1,1]$ use expansion of numbers to base 3. I will be glad to help if this is not clear to you.

Comment: This is a bit late, but [here is a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309080) with several answers showing that $C+C=[0,2]$. Given the symmetry $C=1-C$, this is easily seen to be equivalent to $C-C=[-1,1]$.