# Given an uncountable nowhere dense set $A$ of measure zero, is it true that $A+A$ has a positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(\mathbb{R}, \Omega, \mu)$ is Lebesgue measure space.  Given an uncountable nowhere dense set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(A) = 0$, is it true that $A+A = \{a + b \in \mathbb{R}: a,b \in A\}$ has positive measure, i.e. $\mu(A+A) > 0$?

This is [true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309080/cantor-set-cantor-set-0-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the Cantor set since $C + C = [0,2]$. Would this be true in general?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give some additional context.  For a discussion of what is expected on this site, please read [this answer on the meta site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), as well as the other answers you find there.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Added more context to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Given a base $b$ and a subset $S\subset \{0,\dots,b-1\}$, let
$$C_b(S)=\big\{x\in[0,1)\colon x\text{ has a representation in base $b$ with digits in } S\big\}.$$
For example, $S_2(\{0,1\})=[0,1)$ and $S_3(\{0,2\})$ is $C\setminus\{1\}$, where $C$ is the Cantor set.

Consider $A=S_4(\{0,1\})$; then $A+A=S_4(\{0,1,2\})$. Because of the surjection $A\to[0,1]$ given by interpreting a base-$4$ string as binary, $A$ is uncountable. Similarly to the proof that the Cantor set is nowhere dense and has Lebesgue measure zero, both $A$ and $A+A$ satisfy these conditions.

Comment: *Aside.* $S_3(\{0,2\}) = C$, since $1 = 0.2222\cdots$ in base $3$.  Also $S_2(\{0,1\})=[0,1]$ includes $1$. All your sets $C_b(S)$ are compact as continuous image of compact set $S^{\mathbb N}$..