# Question on the proof that the sum of two Cantor discontinuums on the $[0,1]$ is $[0,2]$.

Tags: geometry, descriptive-set-theory

I'm trying to understand the following lemma(See [here](http://books.google.com.hk/books?hl=zh-CN&id=CCR9k2khTvwC&q=37#v=snippet&q=37&f=false) on googlebooks) on page $37$,  *Nonmeasurable Sets and Functions*, Alexander Kharazishvili(2004):

> $\qquad$**Lemma $\bf 1.$** *Let $C$ denote the Cantor discontinuum on the unit segment $[0,1]$. Then the set* $$C+C=\{x+y:x\in C,y\in C\}$$ *coincides with the segment $[0,2]$.*

It seems to me the Cantor  discontinuum is the Cantor Ternary Set in $\Bbb R$, not a perfect and nowhere dense subset of of $\Bbb R$ in general. But I'm not sure.

In addition, I have no clue why "from the geometric viewpoint, it is almost evident that $$C \times C = \bigcap\{Z_n : n < \omega\}$$ $\ldots$"

Here's the proof:

> **Proof.** We can use the standard geometric argument presented, for example, in $[155]$. Namely, let us introduce a mapping $$\phi:\bf\mathbf R\times\mathbf R\to\mathbf R$$ defined by $$\phi(x,y)=x+y\qquad(x\in\mathbf R,\:y\in\mathbf R).$$ This mapping can be described in another way. Denoting $$l=\{(x,y)\in\mathbf R\times\mathbf R:x+y=0\},$$ we see that $\phi$ is identical with the projection $$pr_l:\mathbf R\times\mathbf R\to\mathbf R\times\{0\}$$ whose direction is determined by the straight line $l$. Now, from the geometric viewpoint it is almost evident that $$C\times C=\cap\{Z_n:n\lt\omega\},$$ where $\{Z_n:n\lt\omega\}$ is some decreasing (with respect to inclusion) sequence of compact subsets of the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and, in addition, the equality $$pr_l(Z_n)=[0,2]$$ holds for any natural number $n$. This fact readily implies, by virtue of the compactness of all sets $Z_n$, that the relation $$pr_l(C\times C)=[0,2]$$ holds true, too, which is equivalent to the relation $C+C=[0,2]$. The lemma has thus been proved.

Comment: The Cantor ternary set is perfect and nowhere dense.

Comment: @minimalrho, Thanks for your comment. I know it's true. I mean I don't know Cantor discontinuum is the Cantor ternary set, or a set that is perfect and nowhere dense, which could be, but not necessarily is the Cantor ternary set.

Comment: There are other proofs.

Comment: For another proof, view http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/measure-of-the-cantor-set-plus-the-cantor-set/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, he’s talking about the middle-thirds Cantor set. $Z_n=C_n\times C_n$, where $C_n$ is the finite union of closed intervals at stage $n$ of the construction of $C$ shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set) for instance. $Z_0=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, $$Z_1=\left(\left[0,\frac13\right]\cup\left[\frac23,1\right]\right)\times\left(\left[0,\frac13\right]\cup\left[\frac23,1\right]\right)\;,$$ and so on. $Z_2$ is shown in the picture for Proof #$1$ [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/cantor5.shtml), which is a more informal version of the argument that you’re reading that should make what’s going on a bit clearer.