# Construct an example in $\mathbf R$ where $A$ and $B$ are two nowhere dense sets but closure of $A + B$ is $\mathbf R$ itself.

Tags: general-topology

Any answers will be appreciated. I know $\mathbf Q$ has closure $\mathbf R$, but can $\mathbf Q$ be expressed as the sum of two nowhere dense sets? Or will some other example work?

Comment: You can make $A$ to be the integers and $B= \sqrt{2} A$

Comment: @PenasRaul This does not seem to work because $A+B\neq\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @user2097 An additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ is either cyclic or dense. Since both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\sqrt{2}\mathbb{Z}$ are additive subgroups and their sum is not cyclic, their sum is dense. On the other hand both are closed with empty interior.

Comment: @egreg The OP wants $A+B=\mathbb{Q}$ if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @user2097 My impression is that the title and the question don't match and that asking about $\mathbb{Q}$ is just an attempt. And there is “Or will some other example work?”

Comment: @egreg You are right. Now I see that OP asked two different questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A+B=\mathbb{Q}$ holds with $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\{q_n-n\}$, where $q_1,q_2,\ldots$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)$.

Comment: Instead of 'denotes', I would say 'enumerates' (or even better, 'is an enumeration of'). But +1.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but why is $B$ nowhere dense?

Comment: @DavidMitra Because $[-n,-n+1)$ contains exactly one point from $B$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A well-known property of the Cantor set (which is nowhere dense) is that $C+C=[0,2]$. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/measure-of-the-cantor-set-plus-the-cantor-set).)

Now, let $K$ be the 1-periodic continuation of Cantor set, i.e., 
$$
K=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}k+C.
$$ 
Then $K$ is nowhere dense, and 
$$
K+K=\mathbb R.
$$