# Two sets $X,Y \subset [0,1]$ such that $X+Y=[0,2]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sumset

> A set $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ is called *nice* if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there are a 
>   positive integer $k$ and some bounded intervals $I_1,I_2,...,I_k$ such that 
>   $X \subset I_1 \cup I_2 \cup \cdots \cup I_k$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^k |I_j|^{\epsilon} < \epsilon$. 
>   Prove that there exist sets $X,Y \subset [0,1]$, both of them *nice*, such that $X+Y = [0,2]$, where $X+Y:=\{x+y\mid x\in X,y\in Y\}.$

This question is from an iberoamerican exam for undergraduate students (ciim 2010).

An attempt to solve this problem can be found at [aops](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h607102p3607714)
but it doesn't seem to be complete or correct. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Take $X=Y=C$, where $C$ is the middle-thirds Cantor set; there are elementary proofs [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/cantor5.shtml).

Comment: Not zero-dimensional set, but set of measure zero!

Comment: As @Yiorgos points out, the problem statement is wrong: the definition given in the problem is for sets of *measure zero*, not for *zero-dimensional* sets. The solution that I suggested in my comment is both zero-dimensional *and* of measure $0$.

Comment: There is an $\varepsilon$ in the exponent as well, so this makes it stronger than being measure $0$, maybe?

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the reference. However the definition given is not measure zero as Yiorgos pointed out. As Henno observed there is an $\epsilon$ in the exponent. I'm not sure if the Cantor set ($X=Y=C$) is the solution. I also removed the terms measure-zero  and dimension zero to avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Yiorgos not set of measure zero, since there is an $\epsilon$ in the exponent.

Comment: @jack: Ah, yes: I didn’t notice the exponent. I’ll leave the Cantor set suggestion there for now in case someone can use it as a starting point.

Comment: It was [Problem 3, Part 1](http://www.impa.br/opencms/pt/eventos/extra/2010_2ciim/attach/prova_espanol_1.pdf) at CIIM 2010 Rio de Janeiro

Comment: nice question ..............+1

Answer (score 1):

The middle thirds [Cantor Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) doesn't work since at stage $N$ there are $2^N$ intervals of length $\frac{1}{3^N}$.  So for some $\epsilon$ the Hausdorff dimension of this Cantor set, the series is more than $0$:

$$  \left(\frac{2}{3^{\epsilon }}\right)^N =1 \longrightarrow \epsilon = \frac{\log 2}{\log 3}  $$

It is also the limit set of the two functions $T_1(x) = \frac{x}{3}$ and $T_2(x) = \frac{x}{3} + \frac{2}{3}$.

If we remove successively smaller percentages, we can get Cantor sets of positive Lebesgue measure.  The [Smith-Volterra-Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) is nowhere-dense and has Lebesgue measure $\frac{1}{2}$.

These disasters come up when you try to show $\int_a^b f'(x) \, dx = f(b) - f(a)$ for certain trig series.

---

Considering this is like the Putnam exam, let's try to take "aggressive" Cantor sets.  Instead of removing the middle $\frac{1}{3}$ at each stage, let's remove the middle $1-\frac{1}{N}$.  Now after stage $N$ there are $2^N$ sets, but these have measure:

$$ 2^N \cdot \left(\frac{1}{N!}\right)^\epsilon \approx \left(\frac{2 e^\epsilon}{N}\right)^N \to 0$$

and this is true for all $\epsilon$.  Using iterated functions we are using $T_{1,N}(x) = \frac{x}{N}$ and $T_{2,N}(x) = \frac{x}{N} + (1-\frac{1}{N})$.  Here are some notes on **[dimension theory](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdbl/dimension-total.pdf)**.

---

Here a lot of work has gone into constructing **nice** sets, but we need *two* nice sets $X,Y\subset [0,1]$ with $X + Y = [0,2]$.  Necessarily $0,1 \in X \cap Y$.

It is certainly true that [$C + C = [0,2]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/measure-of-the-cantor-set-plus-the-cantor-set) I don't think this is true for the set I have constructed.

Another route might be to try building "Cantor sets" using continued fractions whose digits are bounded or avoid a certain number.

$$ A_k = \{ [a_1, \dots, a_k, \dots] : 0 \leq a_i < k \} \subset \mathbb{Q} $$

These sets may be sparse enough and have the sum property you desire.

Comment: It is indeed, not true at all for the Cantor set you have constructed. In fact, one can show for a large family of Cantor sets, there is a dichotomy between the sets that are "too large" (not nice) or "too small" (not satisfying $X+Y=[0,1]$). I'll write more about this if I have the time

Comment: @john Consider the continued fractions $A = \{ [0; a_1, a_2, \dots] : 1 \leq a_i \leq 4, 1 \leq i \}.$ Can you show that A is nice? If A is nice I can solve the problem.

Comment: @Ewan Following the suggestion of John Mangual, do you know if the set of continued fractions $A = \{ [0; a_1, a_2, \dots] : 1 \leq a_i \leq 4, 1 \leq i \}$ is nice? I'm not sure if it's nice, but if the answer is positive I think I can solve the problem.

Comment: @jack any reason in particular $4$?