# Lebesgue measure of Minkowski sum of two similar convex sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

> How to calculate the Lebesgue measure $m(A+\lambda A)$ in terms of $m(A)$ and $\lambda$ where A is a convex set $\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, $\lambda$ is a constant, and addition is Minkowski sum?

My idea about solving it is to first consider the case for $A$ when it is a rectangle, then pass it to the case where $A$ is open set and write it as infinite sum of open sets, then compact set and finally the general case. But, that might be a long path and no guarantee. Any better idea? It should be simple.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume that $\lambda >0$. You only need this:

$$A + \lambda A = (1+ \lambda )A = \{(1+ \lambda) a : a\in A\}$$

when $A$ is convex. Note that $\supset$ is obvious. On the other hand, let $y\in A + \lambda A$. Then by definition, $y = a_1 + \lambda a_2$, where $a_1, a_2 \in A$. Then

$$\frac{1}{1+\lambda} y = \frac{1}{1+ \lambda} a_1 + \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda } a_2 $$

is in $A$, as the right hand side is a convex combination of $a_1, a_2$. Thus $y\in (1+ \lambda)A$.

As a result, we have that 
$$m(A+ \lambda A) = (1+\lambda)^d m(A),$$
where $d$ is the dimension.

Note that in general when $A$ is not convex, $A+A$ might have positive measure even if $A$ is of measure zero. [Cantor set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/measure-of-the-cantor-set-plus-the-cantor-set) is one of the example.

Comment: OK, and therefore the measure of $A+\lambda A$ is just the absolute value of the determinant of the linear transformation $(1+\lambda)I$ multiplied by the measure of $A$.

Comment: @uniquesolution : Ok, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.