# Is the measure of the sum equal to the sum of the measures?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, sumset

Let $A,B$ be subsets in $\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that
$$m(A+B)=m(A)+m(B)?$$
Provided that the sum is measurable.

I think it should not be true, but could not find a counterexample.

Comment: What if $A=B=K$ where $K$ is a Cantor set? In such a case $\mu(K)=0$ but $K+K$ contains an interval.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/measure-of-the-cantor-set-plus-the-cantor-set) might help you !

Comment: To summarize the answers, basically if $A$ and $B$ are intervals, then yes, there is equality, but if they are not connected, then the measure of the sum can be a lot larger.

Comment: I am not sure that A+B is necessarily measurable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I preassume that here $A+B:=\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$.

Counterexample (for Lebesgue measure):

Take $A=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and $B=[0,1]$ (so that $A+B=[0,4]$)

Comment: It seems that your Lebesque example actually does satisfy the condition since the sum is just $[0,2]$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you. Repaired now.

Comment: is it always larger?

Comment: The Lebesgue measure in invariant under translations so $A+\{b\}$ has the same measure as $A$, If $B\neq\varnothing$ then the measure of $A+B$ will not be smaller than the measure of $A$.

Comment: @drhab I assume he is asking if $m(A+B)\ge m(A)+m(B)$ always.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro The answer to that is "no". If $A=\varnothing$ then also $A+B=\varnothing$. So if secondly $m(B)>0$ then $m(A+B)=0<m(B)=m(A)+m(B)$.

Comment: However, if $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, and $A+B$ is measurable, then $m(A + B) \ge m(A) + m(B)$. This is the one-dimensional case of the Brunn-Minkowski inequality.

Comment: @SashoNikolov Nice (I expected that to be true, but had no decent proof of it yet). Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 27):

Another example:
$$A=\mathbb{Z},\quad B=[0,1],\quad A+B=\mathbb{R}.
$$

Answer (score 6):

Let we consider the ternary representation of some number in $(0,1)$:
$$ x= 0.\overline{1022101}_3 $$
Exploiting $0=\frac{0+0}{2},1=\frac{0+2}{2},2=\frac{2+2}{2}$ digit by digit, we may write $x$ as the average between two numbers $a,b$
$$ x = 0.\overline{1022101}_3 = \frac{0.\overline{0022000}_3+0.\overline{2022202}_3}{2}=\frac{a+b}{2} $$
with the property that all their ternary digit belong to $\{0,2\}$. It follows that if $K$ is a [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) in $[0,1]$, $\mu(K)=0$, but $\mu(K+K)\geq 2$, since $K+K$ contains every point of the interval $(0,2)$.

---

This argument also has a discrete analogue in terms of [Sidon sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence) or additive bases.
 For instance, if $Q$ is  the set of integer squares and $E=Q+Q$, $E$ has density zero in $\mathbb{N}$, i.e.
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\left|E\cap[1,n]\right|}{n}=0,$$
but every natural number belongs to $E+E$ by [Lagrange's four-squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem).
If we take $C$ as the set of integer cubes,
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\left|C\cap[-n,n]\right|}{2n+1}=0, $$
but
$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{Z},\qquad n\in \left(C+C+C+C+C\right).$$