# Does there exist a measurable subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, such that $\mu(A)$ is finite, but $\mu(\{a+b|a,b\in A\}) = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure, real-numbers

Does there exist a measurable subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, such that $\mu(A)$ is finite, but $\mu(\{a+b|a,b\in A\}) = \infty$? Here $\mu$ stands for Lebesgue measure.

If such subset exists, it can not be bounded:
Suppose it is. Then there exists such $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \subset [-a;a]$. That results in $\{a+b|a,b\in A\} \subset [-2a;2a]$, from which follows that $\mu(\{a+b|a,b\in A\}) \leq 4a$ is finite.

However, I do not know, how to solve the problem in general.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @bof why not an answer ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting enough you can even find such a set of measure $0$.

Indeed, if $C$ is the tertiary Cantor set then $C+C=\{ a+b : a,b \in C\} =[0,2]$ see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/measure-of-the-cantor-set-plus-the-cantor-set)

Then 
$$A= \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb Z} 2n+C $$
has measure $0$ but $A+A=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Very cute, I like it! Who needs Banach–Tarski when you get these weird paradoxical results free of choice? :)

Comment: +1, this is such a cool result :-)

Answer (score 9):

$A=[0,1]\cup\mathbb Z$ is a closed set, $\mu(A)=1$, and $\{a+b:a,b\in A\}=\mathbb R.$